# How to find the indices of a subset in a list?

Tags: python, list, subset

I have a list of values that I know are increasing, such as

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I'm looking for the indices of the subset that are within some range `[min, max]`. E.g. I want

```
>> subset_indices(x, 2, 4)
[1, 3]
>> subset_indices(x, 1.1, 7)
[1, 5]
```

Is there a nice pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Look at the bisect module. It is designed for this and has the exact functions you want.

Comment: the solution depends on the size of the list. From a simple search algorithm to a tree.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Looks perfect, thanks.

Comment: @jmugz3, *bisect* uses binary search algorithm - AFAIK

Comment: I'm confused as to what this actually does. Can someone explain to me what this is for? What is the 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the recommendations from Kenny Ostrom and volcano, I implemented it simply as

```
import bisect

def subset_indices(sequence, minv, maxv):
    low = bisect.bisect_left(sequence, minv)
    high = bisect.bisect_left(sequence, maxv, lo=low)
    return [low, high]
```

Comment: You could have saved value for minimum index - and used it to lookup maximum index. It will make second lookup more efficient - which may have impact on big data sets.

Comment: @volcano Great idea! I'm using quite a lot of data, so that suggestion is definitely helpful. I added it to the answer.